# Index of an object in the ArrayList according to one of its properties value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList contains Book objects, how can I get the index of a specific object according to its property "ID" value ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(new Book("foods", 1));
   list.add(new Book("dogs", 2));
   list.add(new Book("cats", 3));
   list.add(new Book("drinks", 4));
   list.add(new Book("sport", 5));

   int index =  
}
```

this Book class :

```
public class Book {
    String name;
    int id;

    public Book(String name, int Id) {
        this.name=name;
        this.id=Id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: You wish to get the index of *which* item? Please clarify your question for us.

Comment: i want to get the index of an object according to its ID value

Comment: Use `for` loop to iterate, test each item to find the index.

Comment: Ideally put them into a map by Id, otherwise the stream API answer below will do.

Comment: just a note, you can keep 2 lists separately `name to ids` and `ids to name`, saves time in iterating as number of searches will be large(as far as i guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by using an `IntStream` to generate the indices then use a `filter` operation for your given criteria then retrieve the index using `.findFirst()...` as shown below:

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                     .filter(i -> list.get(i).id == searchId)
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

### For Java Versions Below 8 Solution

As an addition to other, Java 8 working solution, there is a solution for those working with Java versions earlier than 8:

```
int idThatYouWantToCheck = 12345; // here you can put any ID you're looking for
int indexInTheList = -1; // initialize with negative value, if after the for loop it becomes >=, matching ID was found

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).getId == idThatYouWantToCheck) {
        indexInTheList = i;
        break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely what you are looking for:

```
private static int findIndexById(List<Book> list, int id) {
    int index = -1;
    for(int i=0; i < list.size();i++){
        if(list.get(i).id == id){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
int index = findIndexById(list,4);
```

Even if you are using Java 8, for what you are doing streams are not suggested; for-loop is faster than streams. [**Reference**](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html)